# error while writing Java code for Mahout

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, hadoop

I am new to Apache Mahout. I tried to use your code in my environment, but I am facing issues. I know that the post is old, and you may not reply to my query. But I am writing as I am stuck.

I tried to configure Maven in my environment, but due to company policy, I am not able to configure it successfully, so I decided to resolve the dependencies manually, and I installed all the required dependencies one by one. But I am not able to find one last library, I tried looking on internet for 2 days, but no luck. May be someone can help me out here.

I am using Eclipse STS. I did try with Eclipse Mars2, but same problem. I have installed following set of project specific libraries.

Commons-cli-2.0.jar, Google-collection-1.0.jar, hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar, log4j-1.2.13.jar, mahout-core0.2-source.jar, mahout-core0.3-source.jar, mahout-core0.4-job.jar, mahout-core0.7.jar, mahout-core0.8.jar, mahout-math-0.8.jar, mahout-utils-0.5.jar, slf4j-API-1.6.1.jar, slf4j-log4j12-16.1.jar, JRE System Library (JavaSE-1.8.

I have tried various permutation combination for libraries hoping to get my work done. Unfortunatly, its not happening, May be you can help me out.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.ClassifierResult;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.TrainClassifier;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.algorithm.BayesAlgorithm;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.common.BayesParameters;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.datastore.InMemoryBayesDatastore;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.exceptions.InvalidDatastoreException;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.interfaces.Algorithm;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.interfaces.Datastore;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.model.ClassifierContext;
import org.apache.mahout.common.nlp.NGrams;

public class Starter {

    //char var1;
 public static void main( final String[] args ) {
  final BayesParameters params = new BayesParameters();
  params.setGramSize( 1 );
  params.set( "verbose", "true" );
  params.set( "classifierType", "bayes" );
  params.set( "defaultCat", "OTHER" );
  params.set( "encoding", "UTF-8" );
  params.set( "alpha_i", "1.0" );
  params.set( "dataSource", "hdfs" );
  params.set( "basePath", "/tmp/output" );

  //var1 = text.csv;

  try {
      Path input = new Path( "D:\\Apache\\text.csv" );
      Path output = new Path( "D:\\Apache\\output" );
      TrainClassifier.trainNaiveBayes( input, output, params );

      Algorithm algorithm = new BayesAlgorithm();
      Datastore datastore = new InMemoryBayesDatastore( params );
      ClassifierContext classifier = new ClassifierContext( algorithm, datastore );
      classifier.initialize();

      final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[ 0 ] ) );
      String entry = reader.readLine();

      while( entry != null ) {
          List< String > document = new NGrams( entry,
                          Integer.parseInt( params.get( "gramSize" ) ) )
                          .generateNGramsWithoutLabel();

          ClassifierResult result = classifier.classifyDocument(
                           document.toArray( new String[ document.size() ] ),
                           params.get( "defaultCat" ) );

          entry = reader.readLine();
      }
  } catch( final IOException ex ) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  } catch( final InvalidDatastoreException ex ) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Below are the error messages:-

> Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.mahout.common.HadoopUtil.overwriteOutput(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;)V
>
> at org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.mapreduce.bayes.BayesDriver.runJob(BayesDriver.java:39)
>
> at org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.TrainClassifier.trainNaiveBayes(TrainClassifier.java:54)
>
> at Starter.main(Starter.java:42)

I tried looking for “org.apache.mahout.common.HadoopUtil.overwriteOutput” all over the internet, but I fail to get them, there are libraries with the name “org.apache.mahout.common.HadoopUtil”, but it doesnpt contain the required sub library.

Please help.

Comment: remove different Versions of same libs: mahout-core0.7.jar,mahout-core0.8.jar

Comment: The Problem are incompatible library versions

Comment: Hi, tried doing that as well, just keeping one single version, still the issue.At one point of time, I just had 0.7 mahout-core. Similarly, I tested it with 0.8 alone. No success

Comment: please close the thread..I am not getting help from this forum...